# Is time in Exif or other metadata in a Nexus 5x video?

Tags: video, date-and-time, exif

I have some MP4 videos taken with a Nexus 5x.  I no longer have that device.  Which of the Exif or XMP or the metadata (if any) contains time in UTC that the video started or ended?  I'm trying to get them in chronological order with all the still pictures I took.